# How to make Azure Function fire on queue change when using containers?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I've created an Azure Functions app and dockerized it. The container is running and doesn't give me any errors. Now I want this function app to be triggered by a storage queue insertion. I've read the microsoft docs and added the trigger in my function.json file.

```
{
      "name": "myQueueItem",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "searches",
      "connection": "StorageAccountConnectionString"
    }
```

The StorageAccountConnectionString is an app setting which I added to the functions app in the azure portal under configuration.

I verified the existence of the searches queue as well.

Now nothing seems to be happening when I insert a message into the searches queue. The dequeue counts doesn't increment, and the function execution counter also doesn't change.

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

- If you are deploying the docker image to the function app then you can setup the environment variable in the docker file itself.
- just add the following command in your dockerfile.

```
ENV StorageAccountConnectionString = <Your Connection String>
```

- This way there will be a reference to the variable in the docker container. Here my storage queue trigger was working after I add the command.

[image]

You can also refer to this [article](https://dev.to/codeprototype/accessing-application-settings-from-azure-function-apps-in-a-docker-container-1fjg#:%7E:text=$%20docker%20ps%20$%20docker%20exec%20-it%20vigorous_bhaskara,In%20the%20example,%20that%27s%20vigorous_bhaskara%20and%2016527b513905%20respectively.) by Kevin lee

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, but it was fixed by generating a function from VS Code Azure Functions extension. Then the function picked up the queue change.